# Pandas conditional formatting: Highlighting cells in one frame that are unequal to those in another

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles, python-applymap

Given two pandas dataframes df1 and df2 that have exact same schema (i.e. same index and columns, and hence equal size), I want to color just those cells in df1 that are unequal to their counterpart in df2. Any hints?

More generally, if I have a predefined matrix of colors, colormat, that has the same dimensions as df1, can I somehow color each cell of df1 based on the color given in colormat?

Simple example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[3,4,5], 'colB':[6,7,8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[3,4,50], 'colB':[6,70,8]})

colormat = df1.eq(df2).replace({False:'red', True:'green'})
```

When applied to df1, I want df1.loc[2,'colA'] and df1.loc[1, 'colB'] to be colored red, and the other cells green, since 5 != 50 and 7 != 70

Comment: If you gave samples of `df1`, `df2` and this matrix of colors this would be an easier question to answer.

Comment: Good idea, added example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles need to be valid CSS, so change 'red' and 'green' to `'background-color: red'` and `'background-color: green'`, then simply [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) on `axis=None` and pass the `colormat` DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [3, 4, 5], 'colB': [6, 7, 8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [3, 4, 50], 'colB': [6, 70, 8]})

colormat = df1.eq(df2).replace({False: 'background-color: red',
                                True: 'background-color: green'})
df1.style.apply(lambda _: colormat, axis=None)
```

---

Depending on size of the DataFrames [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) may be more performant:

```
colormat = np.where(df1.eq(df2),
                    'background-color: green',
                    'background-color: red')

df1.style.apply(lambda _: colormat, axis=None)
```

---

Both Produce:

[image: styled table]